# Windows 10 task manager not showing mspdbsrv.exe process

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

It seems that Task Manager in Windows 10 is not showing all running processes.

For example, it never shows mspdbsrv.exe from Visual Studio.

Is this a bug or a feature? Is it hardcoded to hide this specific process or is there an API available with which a process can hide itself (which would be a major security issue IMHO).

[image: mspdbsrv.exe not visible in Task Manager]

Answer (score 0):

The process has probably already shutdown and is currently in zombie state.
Meaning that it is only a shell waiting for some shared object (semaphore etc.)
to be released by another process.

The program `mspdbsrv.exe` is automatically spawned when building a Visual Studio
project. All Visual Studio instances normally share one common pdb-server which
will shutdown itself after an idle period (standard is 10 minutes).
Its purpose is to ensure access to `.pdb` files is properly serialized in
parallel builds when multiple instances of the compiler try to access the same
`.pdb` file.

Sometimes because its ghost is still hovering around and holding on
to resources, Visual Studio compilations may fail.
In this case, it can be killed using Process Explorer.

Comment: What do you mean by a "shell"? A process is either running or finished. The handle can still be open for reading the exit code (aka zombie state), but unlike Linux, in Windows a "zombie" process is not visible in the process list, so also not in process explorer. I was also unable to reproduce it using just an open handle to an already finished process.

Comment: By "shell" I mean "empty", just an entry in the process table. This process seems to be running as a system service, so cannot be started from the command-line. Perhaps Process Manager can find some more information about what it's doing.